# How to Write a letter by * and - "Theory"

Tags: javascript

Does anyone have an idea if i would like to write a letter by `*`s

for example `o`

```
---***---
-**---**-
-**---**-
-**---**-
---***---
```

I know I can generate a loop to line by line but I have to make calculation first about the word I would like to write

I am searching for a theory or a rule I can apply so i can minimise the calculations 
I am lazy :p sorry

Comment: There is no *fast* algorithm, just hard-coded mapings. Or you could create image of letter and then read every pixel converting white background to `*` and black to `-`

Answer (score 1):

I think you could have a pre-defined arrays of definitions for each letter. For example, the letter "O" would be something like this:

`[
 [0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0],
 [0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0],
 [0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0],
 [0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0],
 [0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0]
]`

Essentially you could even represent it as an array of strings:

`[
 "000111000",
 "011000110",
 "011000110",
 "011000110",
 "000111000"
]`

Only where the "1" appears will an `*` character be used. You woud still, however, need to loop over these arrays to populate your final output.

I don't think it would be very logical to attempt to calculate this each time, there are a fixed number of characters that you can display and you would only need to define these mappings once.

Answer (score 0):

You can have all the alphabet stored as a tridimensional array `[x,y,z]`
Being `x` the index to the letter 0 for a, 1 for b ... 23 for z, 24 for A and so.
After you get your word, i.e. `Hello` you can compose it as elements 28, 4, 12, 12, 15 (<< these numbers are not the real ones, you have to use the ones in your array)

While iterating the array, each value of `[x]` will give you a bidimensional array with `[y]` the lines and `[x]` for each specific position of a - or a * at the line.

Finally, you can iterate by the lines of the composition for the whole word, having each line of each array to show the values:

```
Line 0: ['--------', '--------', '--------', '--------', '--------']
Line 1: ['--*--*--', '--------', '----*---', '----*---', '--------']
Line 2: ['--*--*--', '--------', '----*---', '----*---', '--------']
Line 3: ['--*--*--', '--****--', '----*---', '----*---', '--****--']
Line 4: ['--****--', '--*-----', '----*---', '----*---', '--*--*--']
Line 5: ['--*--*--', '--**----', '----*---', '----*---', '--*--*--']
Line 6: ['--*--*--', '--*-----', '----*---', '----*---', '--*--*--']
Line 7: ['--*--*--', '--****--', '----*---', '----*---', '--****--']
```